# How to solve "invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start." when building a docker container Ubuntu 20.04 and installing jenkins?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins, ubuntu-20.04, cicd

I am trying to install jenkins on ubuntu:20.04 docker container and policy denied to start jenkins server. below error response when i'm trying to install jenkins.

Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/jenkins.service → /lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service.
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.

How to solve that issue? If it is an issue.

```
...
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
...
```

Comment: With just the error message, it's a little hard to tell what's actually going on.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], especially including your current Dockerfile?  Usually Docker containers don't run init scripts at all, just the single process that's the image's `CMD`, and it might be possible to skip this step entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The policy-rc.d has one sole purpose,it should tell to invoke-rc.d if the action is allowed or not, by using its exit status. From [debian docs](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/policy-rc.d-declarative.8.html)

```
   Debian policy states that packages providing system services need to start those services
   by default, and that the starting of the service should be done by way of the
   /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d script. This script will execute a program /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d if
   it exists, allowing the local system administrator to override behaviour if wanted by
   creating a policy script according to the interface specified and installing it as
   /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d.
```

You should provide us with more information. Your Dockerfile. Are you running Docker inside Docker?